# How to create a Control Flow Diagram like this?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, flow-charts

[image]
Hello everyone, I found this diagram on PezzeYoung's book. I don't understand how they create diagram like this using LateX. I searched online and tryed to use TikZ to create this think, but I didn't find out any way to produce a diagram like this.

Can you please help?

EDIT:

**CODE FOR TIKZ SETUP**

```
\tikzstyle{terminator} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, text centered, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{data}=[trapezium, draw, text centered, trapezium left angle=60, trapezium right angle=120, minimum height=2em]
\tikzstyle{connector} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick]
```

**CODE OF MY DIAGRAM**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm]
    \node [process, fill=lightgray!20] (start) {\textbf{void exec(Process proc)}};
    \node [terminator, below of=start] (b1) {
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, gobble=8, tabsize=4, showstringspaces=false]
    Lock l = new Lock(); 
    int counter;
        \end{lstlisting}};
    \node [terminator, below of=b1] (b2) {
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, gobble=8, tabsize=4, showstringspaces=false]
    l.isLocked()
        \end{lstlisting}};
    \node [terminator, left of=b2, below of=b2] (b3) {
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=Java, gobble=8]
    throw new RuntimeException("Locking error 1");
        \end{lstlisting}};
    \draw[arrow] (start) -- (b1);
    \draw[arrow] (b1) -- (b2);
    \draw[arrow] (b2) -| node[anchor=east] {True} (b3);
    \draw[arrow] (b2) |- node[anchor=west] {False} (b4);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please show the code you have, and what your problems are. Thank you

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: Thank you. // However, we can do code inspection now, but we can't compile your code, which is more than preferred. Kindly have a look at this procedure to upgrade your code for posting here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 . It's easy to follow ;-)  Thank you // BTW, what is your shortcoming? (Adding a screenshot may make it more evident) /// Please include node (b4) ...

Comment: Probably unrelated, by the macro `\tikzstyle` is obsolete. Check the tikz user guide for `\tikzset`

Comment: Hello, please give a fully compilable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
box/.style={
draw,
rectangle, rounded corners=0.4cm,
minimum height=0.8cm,
align=left, 
inner xsep=10pt,
execute at end node={\hspace{10pt}},
label={[circle, draw, minimum size=0.8cm, inner sep=0pt, anchor=center, shift={(-0.4cm-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.4cm-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]north east:#1},
execute at end node={\hspace{20pt}},
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[box=b2] (A) at (0,0) {\{\\\quad char last = argStr.charAt(0);\\\quad StringBuffer argBuf = new StringBuffer\(\);\\\quad for(intcldx = 0;};
\node[box=b3] (B) at (0,-2) {cldx \textless argStr.length();\hspace{20pt}};
\draw[-{Triangle[scale=1.5]}] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two boxes with round label in corner and some code]

Comment: Thank you so much